# writing script for coupled mass system

Tags: python-3.x, valueerror

So i tested a script that can be found in the scipy cookbook. I simply copied everything from the link. https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/CoupledSpringMassSystem.html

When I ran the script it gave me:

t, x1, xy, x2, y2 = loadtxt('two_springs2.dat', unpack=True)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 0)

what's happening here?

Comment: Are you sure you have the file "two_springs2.dat" in the same directory as your script? `loadtxt` is not loading anything.

Comment: yeah it is i just checked